# NULL value count in group by

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

for simplification purposes, I will use simple table attribute (meaning the table is bigger) to demonstrate the issue:

I have the following table test:

```
 id | nbr
----+-----
  1 |   0
  2 |
  3 |
  4 |   1
  5 |   1
 (5 rows)
```

id and nbr are both numeric values

The following query

```
select nbr, count(nbr) from test group by nbr;
```

outputs:

```
 nbr | count
-----+-------
     |     0
   1 |     2
   0 |     1
(3 rows)
```

whereas the query:

```
select nbr, count(*) from test group by nbr;
```

outputs:

```
 nbr | count
-----+------
     |     2
   1 |     2
   0 |     1
 (3 rows)
```

I find it hard to explain the difference between count(nbr) and count(*) regarding null values
can someone explain this to me like I'm five, thanks

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? MySQL explains it in the documentation of function [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

Comment: Kudos for a very clearly written question!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

`count(<expression>)` counts the number of values. Like most aggregate functions, it removes `null` values before doing the actual aggregation.

`count(*)` is a special case that counts the number of rows (regardless of any `null`).

`count` (no matter if `*` or `<expression>`) never returns `null` (unlike most other aggregate functions). In case no rows are aggregated, the result is `0`.

Now, you have done a `group by` on an nullable column. `group by` put's `null` values into the same group. That means, the group for `nbr` `null` has two rows. If you now apply `count(nbr)`, the null values are removed before aggregation, giving you `0` as result.

If you would do `count(id)`, there would be no `null` value to be removed, giving you `2`.

This is standard SQL behavior and honored by pretty much every database.

One of the common use-cases is to emulate the `filter` clause in databases that don't support it natively: http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter#conforming-alternatives

The exceptions (aggregate functions that don't remove `null` prior to aggregation) are functions like `json_arrayagg`, `json_objectagg`, `array_agg` and the like.

Comment: thanks for the answer, givinig the count(<expression>) counts the number of values after taking out null values, how can you explain the line null with count 0, see the output of select nbr, count(nbr) from test group by nbr; above, thanks in advance.

Comment: because the count is independent of the group by you still grouped by nbr.  so the null remains; but the count is independent of the group by.

Answer (score 9):

**MySQL** explains it in the documentation of function [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

> `COUNT(expr)`
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-`NULL` values of expr in the rows retrieved by a `SELECT` statement.
>
> `COUNT(*)` is somewhat different in that it returns a count of the number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain `NULL` values.

---

**PostgreSQL** also explains it in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

> Most aggregate functions ignore `null` inputs, so that rows in which one or more of the expression(s) yield null are discarded. This can be assumed to be true, unless otherwise specified, for all built-in aggregates.
>
> For example, `count(*)` yields the total number of input rows; `count(f1)` yields the number of input rows in which `f1` is non-null, since `count` ignores `null`s; and `count(distinct f1)` yields the number of distinct non-`null` values of `f1`.

Answer (score 4):

`count(*)` count the number of rows  related  to the group by colums. Inpependntly of the fatc the the column in group by contain null or not null values

`count(nbr)` count the number  of rows related to the group by column where nbr is not null

Answer (score 1):

Count with null values:

```
SELECT nbr, COUNT(*) FROM mytables WHERE nbr IS NULL GROUP BY nbr

UNION

SELECT nbr, COUNT(nbr) FROM mytables WHERE nbr IS NOT NULL GROUP BY nbr
```

Comment: Best solution in my opinion. Plain and simple.